# Unable to connect a node to Erlang debugger ErlyBerly

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am learning the Erlang debugger ErlyBerly. Started ErlyBerly as follows.

```
java -jar target/*runnable.jar
```

I have written a simple Erlang application with an infinite loop so that it keeps running. I started the node from erl CLI. Please note that both the Erlang node and ErlyBerly are running on the same Linux machine. The node is listed in ErlyBerly. When I tried to connect to the node, I am getting an error "cannot connect to peer node". What could be the reason?

```
$erl -sname node
(node1@vm-alarm)1>maths:f().
.....
```

I have tried with a long node name node@oc.com as well. The same error is seen.

The Erlyberly [readme](https://github.com/andytill/erlyberly) page says that "Just make sure that the runtime_tools application is available in the code path. If the node was run using erl directly then it will be available by default". I did not understand this fully. What is runtime_tools? How to run the node using erl directly? Please help me in understanding this.

**Following error message is shown:**
[image: Connect_error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly it is because of the error `"rejected since it cannot handle ["BIG_CREATION"]"` while connecting to the node.

To fix it:

You must edit `jinterface` package part in `pom.xml` and make it download from `com.github.rafaelmsoares` instead of `com.github.andytill`

eg:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.rafaelmsoares</groupId>
        <artifactId>jinterface</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
```

more info: https://github.com/andytill/erlyberly/issues/175